# Database mysql from cart to checkout

Tags: mysql, database, checkout, cart

now i'm developing an e-commerce system.
I've table named cart which store the cart_id, product & price.

Now, I want to proceed with the checkout. When the customer click checkout button, all the items in cart will become 1 order. But I have no ides how the order table will look like? because in 1 order may got many cart_id.

anyone got idea for this table? from cart to checkout.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: yes, in order table..i put id, cartid1, cartid2, and so..
if user1 got 3 products in his/her cart (means his/her got 3 cart_id: 1, 2, 3), and continue to checkout. the value of cart.card_id will be inserted into order.cardid1. same goes to other 2 products.

but what if user buy many products? should i put many fields cartid in order?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By what I have understand,

- you can have several product in one cart
- you can have several cart in one order

Am I right?

If this is the case, the best way I think would be to create 3 tables, with one-to-many relationship between the tables:

[image]